# Unknown uint8_t type in pycparser

Tags: python, c, pycparser

I am trying to parse a C function declaration. As it has `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` in it, pycparser is unable to recognize this type.

```
typedef enum tagReturnCode {SUCCESS, FAIL} ReturnCode;

typedef struct tagEntry
{
    char* key;
    char* value;
} Entry;

typedef struct tagNode
{
    Entry* entry;

    struct tagNode* next;
} Node;

typedef struct tagHash
{
    unsigned int table_size;

    Node** heads;

} Hash;

void test(uint8_t res[], int* op1[], int op2[], char n);
```

This is code that I want to parse and create ast of that, but it gives error for function declaration of test for parameter with uint8_t as identifier

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/func_calls.py", line 48, in <module>
    show_func_calls(filename, func)
  File "examples/func_calls.py", line 34, in show_func_calls
    ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True,cpp_args= r'-I../utils/fake_libc_include')
  File "./pycparser/__init__.py", line 90, in parse_file
    return parser.parse(text, filename)
  File "./pycparser/c_parser.py", line 152, in parse
    debug=debuglevel)
  File "./pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 331, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
  File "./pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 1199, in parseopt_notrack
    tok = call_errorfunc(self.errorfunc, errtoken, self)
  File "./pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 193, in call_errorfunc
    r = errorfunc(token)
  File "./pycparser/c_parser.py", line 1865, in p_error
    column=self.clex.find_tok_column(p)))
  File "./pycparser/plyparser.py", line 67, in _parse_error
    raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: /usr/include/stdint.h:48:23: before: uint8_t
```

How to include these types in pycparser?

Comment: Does [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/on-parsing-c-type-declarations-and-fake-headers) help?

Comment: WARNING: Token 'UINT8_T' defined, but not used
WARNING: There is 1 unused tokenWARNI
 pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: examples/c_files/hash.c:29:11: before: uint8_t


I am getting this error I have included uint8_t in lexer.py

Comment: `#include <inttypes.h>`

Comment: Included  # include <inttypes.h> in my c file still same error occures

Comment: The error complains about `UINT8_T` being unknown, your question and the type I have heard of refers to `uint8_t` which is different. Please clarify. I also think that the message you qutoed (a warning by the way, not an error) does not complain about not recognising it. It just says "Hey, it was defined but never used." Which also can be explained by a mismatch of upper and lower case.... Consider providing a [mre].